# Can't upgrade from 18.04.1 LTS to 18.10

Tags: 18.10

I run the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` but I get the following message:

```
upgrades to the development release are only available from the latest supported release
```

What's the deal? Do I just need to wait a little while longer?

Comment: What do you believe the `-d` flag does? If you are unsure, look it up.

Comment: The current development release is Ubuntu 19.04 (not 18.10).  Check your 'software & updates' to see if you machine is only checking for long-term-support releases, or any-new-release, because if it's the long-term-support the -d will bump you to 20.04 when it's in development (which will be awhile yet to wait, and no 18.04.1 isn't the latest release; it's 18.10; you need to jump to 18.10 before you go to 19.04 [development release] as error states)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Remove all no longer required packages:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

Next, open and edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file and set **Prompt=normal** to avoid No new release found message. Save the file.

Run:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If upgrading before the official 18.10 release date or while the upgrade from 18.04 is still not available use -d to perform upgrade:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: Why the dist-upgrade? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: from man:

   dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
   of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
   expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
   command may remove some packages.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was unclear about the point: dist-upgrade is used for release-upgrades in Debian, not Ubuntu. That step is superfluous in Ubuntu, and indeed may confuse some folks. The OP has not yet clarified if they want 18.10 or 19.04, so the answer should be clear about each. These kinds of questions usually crop up when the OP is typing incantations that they don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are upgrading from `version A` to higher `version B`. Before you upgrade to B, your system must have updated A, as on present date. So, you should update and upgrade the current version (18.04) before you start an upgrade to 18.10.

Issue the commands given below:

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Now you can upgrade as you were doing (and remember what @guiverc mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

**Enable upgrading to non-LTS versions**

This time I had to do an extra step:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Then:

- "Updates" tab
- "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown
- "For any new version"

[image]

TODO how to do it from the command line only?

Then as usual:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Without the `For any new version` setting, it failed to find the new version with:

```
No new release found.
```

Also note that the upgrade is not released at the exact same time as the 18.10 disk comes out, it seems that you have to wait a few days until 18.04.1 is released before upgrading.

For some reason, `apt-get` missed one of the upgrades and I got:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."
```

only `apt` worked.

I advise against `-d` unless you really know what you are doing as that upgrades to unstable development versions, which is not something that most users want.

Comment: This allows me to upgrade to 19.10, but not 20.04. Any ideas?

Comment: @NativeCoder I also can't update yet either with "No new release found.", but I think it is because the upgrade is not yet available: every time they first release the clean ISO, and only after a few days/weeks do they enable the upgrade. Also 20.04 is LTS, so the above instructions should not help.

Comment: I ended up re-imaging with Kubuntu 20.04. There were some KDE improvements that I simply couldn't do without :)